# ERROR: file:///content does not appear to be a Python project: neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, transformer-model

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11u6leEKvqE0CCbvDHHKmCxmW5GxyjlBm?usp=sharing

setup.py file is in transformers folder(root directory). But this error occurs when I run

```
!git clone https://github.com/huggingface/transformers
!cd transformers
!pip install -e .
!pip install -r transformers/examples/pytorch/translation/requirements.txt
```

Can anyone tell me why is this happening?

Comment: I don't see that error anywhere on that page.

Comment: run the first 5 cells or just last 2 cells

Comment: The problem appears to be the error in the PREVIOUS cell, that it couldn't clone the project because the directory already exists.

Answer (score 2):

This error message typically means that Python is unable to find a **setup.py** file or a **pyproject.toml** file in the directory where it is looking for one.

If you are trying to create a new Python project, make sure that your project directory contains a setup.py file or a pyproject.toml file, as one of these is required for a Python project to be considered "installable".

Please read [packaging.python.org/en/latest](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/) to understand how packaging works in Python.

Comment: Was this created by a bot?  Because this answer does not address the problem in any way.

Comment: @TimRoberts sir, long back,In my case, missed that files that why faced the same issue, so I thought, this might helpful.

Answer (score 1):

@TheHungryCub said right to you.
The cause is that you are not in `transformers` folder and that's why: *"Python is unable to find a **setup.py** file or a **pyproject.toml** file"* as was said before.

Command `!cd transformers` from your code doesn't change directory in Colab.
You just simply have to use `%cd transformers` instead and delete `transformers` from `!pip install -r transformers/examples/pytorch/translation/requirements.txt`

The whole script will be:

```py
!git clone https://github.com/huggingface/transformers
%cd transformers
!pip install -e .
!pip install -r examples/pytorch/translation/requirements.txt
```

Comment: `%cd transformers` did the trick.